# Globally mock a function in Jest/Enzyme in React

Tags: reactjs, mocking, jestjs, enzyme

Oftentimes I have functions that are imported into a React component that I want to test using jest/enzyme.

Normally, I can access a function defined in a component through wrapper.instance().functionName and then test if the function has been called. Similarly, I can pass a mock function in as props when mounting a component in a test, and then checking to see if that component has been called. However, I have no methods of testing functions that are imported into components (not defined internally or as props).

Is there a way to use jest/enzyme to define a global mock function that will be used in a component test that will override the implementation of function of the same name that has been imported into the component I'm testing?

Comment: If you feel the need to test that function, test it individually, or turn it into a prop on your components.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that is possible.

There are many different ways to mock modules or individual functions within modules.

---

Here is one example:

lib.js

```jsx
export const importedFunc = () => 'original';
```

code.js

```jsx
import * as React from 'react';
import { importedFunc } from './lib';

export class SimpleComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (<div>{ importedFunc() }</div>);
  }
}
```

code.test.js

```jsx
import * as React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import * as lib from './lib';
import { SimpleComponent } from './code';

test('SimpleComponent', () => {
  const spy = jest.spyOn(lib, 'importedFunc');
  spy.mockReturnValue('mocked');
  const wrapper = shallow(<SimpleComponent />);
  expect(wrapper.html()).toBe('<div>mocked</div>');  // Success!
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();  // Success!
});
```

---

[`jest.spyOn`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname) wraps a function in a spy, and you can change how the spy behaves with any of its [methods](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api) such as [`mockReturnValue`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api#mockfnmockreturnvaluevalue), [`mockImplementation`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api#mockfnmockimplementationfn), etc.

[`jest.mock`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options) lets you mock an entire module.

[Manual mocks](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks) allow you to create module mocks that can be used across tests.

Comment: thanks so much! would this same configuration work if i was using mount instead of shallow?

Comment: @Dog yep!  Once a function is mocked like this it will return the mocked value no matter how it is called